# Have Validation with DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList that is binded to a DataSource on the PageLoad of a page. In this DropDown List I've added a Select value as the default value. On the bottom of this drop down list and some textboxes I have a Add button. How do I add a validation on the dropdown list so that if the User leaves the value as "Select" he/she can not Click the add button unless he/she selects another value.

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblItems" runat="server" Text="SemesterCode: "></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text=" -- Select -- " Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "onchange" method for a drop down list.  When the value of the DDL is changed call a JS function that will enable the other buttons/required fields.

```
function validateThingy(val) {
  return (val != -1)
}

function calledOnChange(val) {
  if (validateThingy(val)) {
    //enable the buttons
  } else {
    //Keep the button disabled
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Selected index of your dropdownlist If it is 0 so alerts a message else puts your logic likewise

```
if(ddlItems.SelectedIndex==0){
Response.Write("Please choose any value");
}else{
 //Put your logic here
}
```